# Why can't I send a cv2 video source?

Tags: python, opencv, mpi, pickle

I tried to use MPI scatter to send a cv2 Video Capture source to different processes. That way, each process would have a handle to retrieve frames.

```
if rank == 0:
  video_source = cv2.VideoCapture('my_video.avi')
  source_list = [video_source] * world_communicator.Get_size()
else:
  source_list = None
data = world_communicator.scatter(source_list, root=0)
# Do stuff with access to the video source...
```

However, I get the following error with this code.

```
[dfaux@ubiquitous mpi_practice]$ mpirun -n 2 python cv2_video_practice.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cv2_video_practice.py", line 93, in <module>
    process_video(source, destination, kernel)
  File "cv2_video_practice.py", line 58, in process_video
    data = comm.scatter(frame_counts, root=0)
  File "Comm.pyx", line 874, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.scatter (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:68023)
  File "pickled.pxi", line 656, in mpi4py.MPI.PyMPI_scatter (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:32402)
  File "pickled.pxi", line 131, in mpi4py.MPI._p_Pickle.dumpv (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:26847)
  File "pickled.pxi", line 81, in mpi4py.MPI._p_Pickle.dump (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:26188)
cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'cv2.VideoCapture'>: it's not the same object as cv2.VideoCapture
```

Why can I not pickle a video source? Why is `<type 'cv2.VideoCapture'>` not the same object as `cv2.VideoCapture`?

Comment: Obviously the `cv2.VideoCapture` class is not serialisable. Why not pass the name of the file to the other ranks and have them create their own `VideoCapture` objects?

Comment: Would that be the same thing as sending many, many frames to the different processes? Also, why isn't `cv2.VideoCapture` serializable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cv2.VideoCapture` is not a list of all of the vectors. Rather, it's a handle that is pointing to a certain frame in the video. That way, it doesn't make sense to scatter such a object to a bunch of other processes. Instead, I'd suggest opening a handle in each process, and then having each process start from a different frame:

```
source.set(cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, start_frame)
```